# How to change the background color of div onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a multiple choice test in HTML and I am using "div"s as answer options. When one option (div) is clicked, its background color should be changed. Here is my code:

```
        <div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 1</div>
        <div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 2</div>
        <div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 3</div>
      </div>

      <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("option");

        function select() {
          div.setAttribute("id", "optionSelected");
        }
      </script>
```

CSS code:

```
#option {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#optionSelected {
  background-color: #008080;
}
```

When I click any of the divs only the first div's background changes, because they all have the same id.

Comment: Please post rest of the "options" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to assign the class based on ID (which as pointed out is not correct to have duplicates), you could instead just use the event target:

```js
function select(e) {
  // Unset selected class from other options
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.option-list .option-selected');
  selected.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('option-selected');
  });
  e.target.classList.add('option-selected');
}
```

```css
.option {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
}
.option-selected {
  background-color: #008080;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-list">
  <div class="option option-selected" onclick="select(event)">Option 1</div>
  <div class="option" onclick="select(event)">Option 2</div>
  <div class="option" onclick="select(event)">Option 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And better yet would be to put all code in the same place instead of using the onclick attribute.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

This is my time posting an answer so sorry if it's not the best.

This is the simpliest way to do it I could think of right now.

You would have to change this

```
<div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 1</div>
<div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 2</div>
<div id="option" onclick="select()">Option 3</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="option1" class="option" onclick="select('option1')">Option 1</div>
<div id="option2" class="option" onclick="select('option2')">Option 1</div>
<div id="option3" class="option" onclick="select('option3')">Option 1</div>
```

So you have a way of distinguishing between the different divs. Also each element would call the function specifying which element should be changed.

---

Then add an parameter to the function so you can specify which element you want to change.

The other line of code replaces the current class "option" with "optionSelected".

```
<script>
    function select(id) {

        var div = document.getElementById(id);

        div.classList.replace("option", "optionSelected");

    }
</script>
```

---

Finally just change the CSS rules to classes.

```
.option {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.optionSelected {
  background-color: #008080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the same ID to all the divs.  ID's must be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should never assign multiple elements the same ID, they should always be different ID's.

2) You could instead use a class, and then call that within the JavaScript function.

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("option");
function select() {
    div.setAttribute("class", "optionSelected")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now the color is not changing.

Comment: You also have to change the HTML for instead of id it is class

Comment: That won't work since the div variable contains a NodeList, not a single element.

Answer (score 0):

so, this is what you've asked for but don't you want to use a drop down box instead?

```js
function select(opt) {
           var div = document.getElementById(opt);
          div.setAttribute("class", "optionSelected");
        }
```

```css
#option {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.optionSelected {
  background-color: #008080;
}
```

```html
<div id="option1" onclick="select('option1')">Option 1</div>
        <div id="option2" onclick="select('option2')">Option 2</div>
        <div id="option3" onclick="select('option3')">Option 3</div>
```

Comment: This will give you a `TypeError` after multiple clicks since you're changing the ID that `getElementById` is searching for

Comment: you're right.  I adjusted the answer accordingly.  Your answer below with toggle is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your project up using classes, if you want to use Id's here is a way to do that.

```
        <div id="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 1</div>
        <div id="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 2</div>
        <div id="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 3</div>
      </div>

      <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("option");

        function select(opt) {

          opt.setAttribute("id", "optionSelected");
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: This is working but I had to include 3 selector in css. Can I use single css selector for all options.

Comment: I have changed the code in the answer for you to work with only one ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify what you're trying to do by adding `this` as an argument to your function (added color toggle on each click):

```html
<div class="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 1</div>
<div class="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 2</div>
<div class="option" onclick="select(this)">Option 3</div>

<script>
  function select(el) {
    el.classList.toggle("optionSelected");
  }
</script>
<style>
  .option {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .optionSelected {
    background-color: #008080;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without javascript, using just css.

```css
.option {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer; /* add if you want */
}

/*
    When the div with the unique id gets focus
    due to a click the background color is applied
*/
#option1:focus, #option2:focus, #option3:focus {
    background-color: #008080;
}
```

```html
<!--
  Add a class for the background color that applies to the
  three divs, and add unique id's to each div
-->
<div>
  <div class="option" id="option1" tabindex="1">Option 1</div>
  <div class="option" id="option2" tabindex="2">Option 2</div>
  <div class="option" id="option3" tabindex="3">Option 3</div>
</div>
```